# SQL Server using CROSS APPLY to avoid duplicate records in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where there is no primary key or any unique column(No any auto increment column).

And I have to select records from that table avoiding duplicate records. I have used `ROW_NUMBER()` function for that and it's working for me.

Here is the working code

```
     WITH Result AS
        (
        SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                                          CategoryName
                                         ,ProductGroup
                                         ,Brand
                                         ,Division 
                                         ,ProductNo                                                                                                                     
                                         ,LocationNo                                                                                         
                                         ,Season                                                                                                
                                         ,Year                                                                                          
                                         ,Month                                                                                         
                                         ,Week                                                                                          
                                         ,Day                                                                                           
                                         ,DemandQty
                                      ), 0) AS RN, * 
        FROM TABLE_1
   )
SELECT * 
FROM Result AS D

WHERE RN IN
 (
    SELECT MAX(RN) MAX_RN
    FROM Result 
    GROUP BY
   CategoryName
  ,ProductGroup
  ,Brand
  ,Division 
  ,ProductNo                                                                                                                    
  ,LocationNo                                                                                        
  ,Season                                                                                               
  ,Year                                                                                         
  ,Month                                                                                            
  ,Week                                                                                         
  ,Day                                                                                          
  ,DemandQty
)
```

This gives the result by avoiding duplicate records.

What I need to do is without writing this `WITH` clause I need to write it using `CROSS APPLY` because it'll take too much time to select records when there are about **500000** records with the Row Number

So far I tried to re-write the query just like below to avoid duplicate records.

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE_1 d
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
TABLE_1 x
WHERE x.[Season] = d.Season
AND ISNULL(x.[Brand]            ,'')= ISNULL(d.[Brand]            ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[Division]         ,'')= ISNULL(d.[Division]         ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[CategoryName]     ,'')= ISNULL(d.[CategoryName]     ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[ProductGroup]     ,'')= ISNULL(d.[ProductGroup]     ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[ProductNo]        ,'')= ISNULL(d.[ProductNo]        ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[LocationNo]       ,'')= ISNULL(d.[LocationNo]       ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[Year]             ,'')= ISNULL(d.[Year]             ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[Month]            ,'')= ISNULL(d.[Month]            ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[Week]             ,'')= ISNULL(d.[Week]             ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[Day]              ,'')= ISNULL(d.[Day]              ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[DemandQty]        ,'')= ISNULL(d.[DemandQty]        ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[DeletionIndicator],'')= ISNULL(d.[DeletionIndicator],'')
AND ISNULL(x.[CreatedBy]        ,'')= ISNULL(d.[CreatedBy]        ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[CreatedOn]        ,'')= ISNULL(d.[CreatedOn]        ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[UpdatedBy]        ,'')= ISNULL(d.[UpdatedBy]        ,'')
AND ISNULL(x.[UpdatedOn]        ,'')= ISNULL(d.[UpdatedOn]        ,'')
) y
```

But it's not giving the correct result for me still duplicate records are coming?

Assume that there are 10 identical rows along with other rows, I need to retrieve only one record from those 10 identical records along with other rows that are not duplicated.

Is there any way to do this without using `ROW_NUMBER` and `WITH` ?

Comment: Don't use CROSS APPLY here.. SQL Server supports DISTINCT and GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT just fine. Albeit potentially slow[er] for non-index columns, but that's not going to be fixed with a CROSS APPLY ..

Comment: I think you are using `ROW_NUMBER()` incorrectly. Why do you need `WHERE RN IN (SELECT MAX(RN) ` if you can just add the PARTITION BY into the OVER() clause of the ROW_NUMBER() function and get the result straight away. To get the MAX(RN) you just need to order by in the descending order

Comment: @cha can you provide a small example?

Comment: I'm doing this because there may be several identical records in this table and I need to avoid those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicates you can use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      CategoryName
     ,ProductGroup
     ,Brand
     ,Division 
     ,ProductNo         
     ,LocationNo                 
     ,Season                        
     ,Year                  
     ,Month                 
     ,Week                  
     ,Day                   
    ,DemandQty
FROM TABLE_1;
```

Or `GROUP BY`:

```
 SELECT
      CategoryName
     ,ProductGroup
     ,Brand
     ,Division 
     ,ProductNo         
     ,LocationNo                 
     ,Season                        
     ,Year                  
     ,Month                 
     ,Week                  
     ,Day                   
    ,DemandQty
FROM TABLE_1
GROUP BY
      CategoryName
     ,ProductGroup
     ,Brand
     ,Division 
     ,ProductNo         
     ,LocationNo                 
     ,Season                        
     ,Year                  
     ,Month                 
     ,Week                  
     ,Day                   
     ,DemandQty;
```

For comparing values which can contain `NULL` instead of

`AND ISNULL(x.[Brand],'')= ISNULL(d.[Brand],'')` you can use:

```
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT
      x.CategoryName
     ,x.ProductGroup
     ,x.Brand
     ,x.Division 
     ,x.ProductNo         
     ,x.LocationNo                 
     ,x.Season                        
     ,x.Year                  
     ,x.Month                 
     ,x.Week                  
     ,x.Day                   
     ,x.DemandQty
  INTERSECT
  SELECT
      d.CategoryName
     ,d.ProductGroup
     ,d.Brand
     ,d.Division 
     ,d.ProductNo         
     ,d.LocationNo                 
     ,d.Season                        
     ,d.Year                  
     ,d.Month                 
     ,d.Week                  
     ,d.Day                   
     ,d.DemandQty
)
```